# A reference to the soul of a Tzaddik like an eyelash in milk

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, avot-patriarch-fathers, soul

I know that somewhere in something I have read there is a comment that someone (Yaakov avinu?) was so spiritually pure/holy that his soul did not cling to the earthly shell that was his body but came out with no resistance. The image was that of drawing an eyelash from a bowl of milk.

I think. I certainly don't think I could make up that image.

The problem is I can't remember who said it, where I read it or about whom. A web search of relevant terms didn't quickly turn anything up. The Stone Chumash (when discussing Yaakov) likens the death as "removing a coat" but that's not the visual I'm looking for.

I'm wondering if anyone recognizes the reference and can help me with a source. I don't mean this as a riddle or a scavenger hunt -- I would really like this source for a discussion I am having elsewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Gemara in [Brachos 8a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=8&format=pdf) says מיתת נשיקה is "נשיקה דמיא כמשחל בניתא מחלבא" which Rashi explains to mean כמושך נימת שער מתוך החלב--like pulling a hair out of milk.

Comment: ok...so maybe it was a hair and not an eyelash. This is great! TY